# bootstrap datepicker opening at wrong position

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I am using bootsrap datepicker on user registraion form. I have triggered the datepicker using following code:

```
$(function(){
        $("#dob").datepicker({
            autoclose: true,
            format : 'mm-dd-yyyy',
            orientation: 'top'
        });
});
```

My HTML input looks like:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input text required" aria-required="true">
    <label for="dob">Dob</label>
    <input type="text" required="required" id="dob" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" class="form-control" name="data[User][dob]" aria-required="true"/>
   </div>
</div>
```

You can check it at [link](http://globalmarriage.in/users/add)
Normally datepicker works fine in my other projects. But unable to find the real issue in this project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like you did an override of the rules for `.dropdown-menu` in `style.css` line 238 `right: 0 !important;`... maybe for a menu?. It's either you increase the specificity of that rule to match exactly where you want it changed, or it will continue to apply to any element with class `.dropdown-menu`, which I believe is also used by the date-picker html.

Good luck mate